# RabbitMQ - Log for Purge of Queues

Tags: rabbitmq

There are several posts out there that show how to purge a queue from the administrator console, command line, and via code. I'm trying to find out if this command is issued, if there is a log that tracks that.

I'm trying to track down some missing messages from a Linux box to a Windows box. I've looked at the log files and don't see anything special there for the date time and also have looked at up times of Rabbitmq, Python, and Erlang, which I use for sending the messages. The Python code has a try catch around it and is to write any exceptions or errors to a log file, but I don't have any reported info.

The issue occurred yesterday and the processes seem to of been running for weeks. The window of issue was about 5 minutes.

One of the options I'm trying to eliminate is trying to see if someone manually purged the queue and I'm curious if they did, where would this be logged (need for both Windows and Linux). I have this as a reference https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html but it doesn't clearly show if these commands are logged and if so, which file it would be logged in.

Comment: RabbitMQ doesn't log when a queue.purge is issued

Comment: @old_sound Thank you for the info. Is there a way to do verbose logging to see all messages outgoing and incoming on the different servers? e.g. For mysql I have a log file setup to /var/log/mysqld.log which I monitor all commands issued against the mysql engine. Having something similar for RabbitMQ would help me troubleshoot things further.

Comment: See https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html